# Exposing c++ model in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I have created this c++ class and exposed to a Qml ListView however, it has some problems. I can view that there are items in the list, however I am not able to see any data (I see 25 empty buttons). In the console, the following message is displayed: "type is undefined". I have checked and type should correctly a full string;

```
ListView{
    id: listView
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: postsModel
    delegate: Component{

        Button{
            text: type
        }
    }
}

#include "listmodel.h"

ListModel::ListModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{

}
QString ListItem::type() const
{
return m_type;
}

QVariantMap ListItem::dataMap() const
{
return m_dataMap;
}
void ListModel::addElement(const ListItem& element)
{
beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
m_elementsList << element;
endInsertRows();
}
QVariant ListModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const
{
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_elementsList.count())
         return QVariant();

    const ListItem &item= m_elementsList[index.row()];
    if (role == TypeRole)
        return item.type();
    else if (role == DataRole)
        return item.dataMap();
    return QVariant();
}
int ListModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent) const {
     return m_elementsList.count();
}
QHash<int, QByteArray> ListModel::roleNames()
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[TypeRole] = "type";
    roles[DataRole] = "dataMap";
    return roles;
}
```

Comment: `const ListItem &ListItem` It's considered very poor style to give an instance the same name as its type, it makes your code difficult to read.

Comment: You should also start with the standard roles, and only when they work move to custom ones. Return the type as a regular `DisplayRole` as well. You thus decrease the number of things that could go wrong.

Comment: Have you tagged the class with `Q_OBJECT` macro in the header file? This could explain the error `type is undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the solution to my problem. The problem was that the ListView was not being updated by the model that I implemented. This was due to my mistake consisting in not calling beginInsertRows() and endInsertRows() functions.